# Simple ZSH function and files with spaces in their name

Tags: whitespace, filenames, zsh, expansion

I have put the following function into my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
function note() {
    vim $HOME/Dropbox/$1.md
}
```

When I call it with `note "20150209-132501-Recx-new note today.md"` for example it creates a new file but with the file name "20150209-132501-Recx-new". I realise this is a simple question but how do I get it to create the note with the full name?

Comment: As long as you quote the filename (or at least the white spaces) when calling `note` it should work. At least it does for me on zsh-5.0.5, It is possible that it does not work on older versions (before 5.0). Have you tried to quote the complete path inside the function with double quotes (`vim "$HOME/Dropbox/$1.md"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell performs parameter substitution and word-splitting in this order.
This means you eventually execute

```
vim /home/username/Dropbox/20150209-132501-Recx-new note today.md.md
```

I.e. you call vim with three file names. If you want to suppress word-splitting on the substituted part, you must use quotes *in the function definition* as well:

```
function note() {
    vim "$HOME/Dropbox/$1.md"
}
```

and call it with

```
note "20150209-132501-Recx-new note today"
```

**EDIT 1:** This version of `note` concatenates all args with a single space:

```
function note() {
    filename=$1
    while test $# -gt 1; do shift; filename="$filename $1"; done
    vim "$HOME/Dropbox/$filename.md"
}
```

**EDIT 2:** This might be even easier:

```
function note() {
    vim "$HOME/Dropbox/$*.md"
}
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear. What I want to do is call the function like this:`note 20150209-132501-Recx-new note today` and have it execute this: `vim "20150209-132501-Recx-new note today"`. Putting `vim "$HOME/Dropbox/$1.md"` in the function does not achieve that. Effectively the quotes get ignored

Comment: @pdoak: That's impossible. The shell always splits words at spaces. You **must** use quotes if spaces shall be part of a file name.

Comment: Do you mean that what I want to achieve is impossible or that putting `"$HOME/Dropbox/$1.md"` in quotes will not achieve what I want. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @podak It is impossible to have the shell instruct to treat `vim x y z` as running vim with a single argument `x y z`. It might work with a DOS shell, but a Unix shell is different. Spaces are used to delimit words. However, there might be a way to concatenate arguments in a shell function and treat the result as a single file name. Is that what you want?

Comment: It sounds as though that is what I want. How do I do that?

Comment: @pdoak Ok, see the edited answer. I think it does what you want :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both but neither worked I'm afraid.

Comment: @pdoak Can you be more specific? What is the name of the file created? What is the expected name? Be sure to tell exactly what command you enter, with quotes and all, if any.

Comment: `"$HOME/Dropbox/$1.md"` worked. I had not reloaded the .zshrc. Sorry for the oversight. I am just trying to use the terminal more and had forgotten that I needed to reload the .zshrc after changing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @pdoak He, forgetting to source a changed file--happens to the best of us. Glad to be of help!