# ZSH function to create file in current directory

Tags: function, vim, zsh

I have this function to create a file in the current directory:

```
function note() {
   vim "$PWD/$*.md"
}
```

If I type `note 2015 - new note`, I get a vim file with a file name of "0". Whereas, if I type `note new note - 2015`, I get a vim file as expected named "new note - 2015.md". What is causing this to happen and how can I fix it.

I had a similar query yesterday [Simple ZSH function and files with spaces in their name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410891/simple-zsh-function-and-files-with-spaces-in-their-name) which Jens got working for me and I have tried to use the same logic here but replacing $HOME with $PWD.

Thanks

ZSH - zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)

VIM - 7.4.258

Comment: Did you try leaving out $PWD? The default would be your current working directory anyhow.

Comment: Joe. Just tried that and it didn't work. Interestingly, though if I type vim "2015.md", it launches vim and briefly shows the file name as "2015.md" but then immediately changes to "0" \[New File\].

Comment: Do you see the same when you launch Vim with `vim -N -u NONE "..."`?

Comment: Which vim and and zsh versions do you have (add them in the question). Using zsh 4.3.17 and vim 7.3, i have no problem with your function. Maybe you have some alias conflicts or strange options with vim

Comment: If I launch vim with `vim -N -u NONE "..."`, the buffer in named correctly as "2015.md". I think it is a either a plugin or something in the .vimrc which is causing the issue but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a vim plugin called [file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line). Once I disabled this plugin creating a new file with any name worked as expected.